# get printer information

Tags: printing, cups

I'm looking for an API or command-line interface to access printer details in CUPS.

`lpstat -t` gives

- information about the scheduler
- a list of devices for each printer
- printer names
- printer status

but I'm looking to also get information about the printer's location, driver, description, and defaults. I a can see the details in the CUPS web interface, but I'm not sure which command to use to get the information from a command line.

Since I want to use this programmatically, an API would be best, but I haven't found one yet, even for the basic information. Right now I'm just parsing the output of `lpstat`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found an API to CUPS for python. Should be straightforward enough to create a web API using [hug](https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug) so any other language can access it.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycups